# How do I convert this end indexing in MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I wanted to convert the fspecial('motion', len, theta) function from the image processing toolbox in MATLAB over to Python but I am stuck at this one line that no matter how I look at it makes no sense to me.

`h(end+(1:end)-1,end+(1:end)-1) = dist2line;`

h is a 2 dimensional array and dist2line is also a 2-D array. All I know is that arr(end) in matlab is arr[-1] in Python but how does that `(1:end)` inside of the indexing work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: `h(end)` can also be written as `h(length(h))`. With this tip, I believe you can work it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If `h` is a 2d array, then it has the dimensions `size(h, 1) x size(h, 2)`, so you can basically replace `end` with the corresponding size, so you'd get

```
s = size(h);
h(s(1)+(1:s(1))-1, s(2)+(1:s(2))-1) = dist2line;
```

Note that when you have a vector of indices in *both* dimensions, you basically extract a *rectangular* submatrix of `h` unlike in python.

Comment: Thanks but I still get a syntax error with the (1:s[1]) and (1:s[2]) in python unfortunately

Comment: Well then I have the impression that your problem is not only MATLABbut also  the *python* side. In MATLAB `a:b` can be considered a vector that makes sense outside of indexing - in python the colon operator only makes sense directly inside the square brackets. So as soon as you parethesize that will fail. I recommend looking up the indexing syntax as well as the `slice()` object in python. Also note that python has `0`-based indexing while MATLABs indexing is `1`-based. And if you have questions regarding that don't hesitate to write a new question. But this is out of the scope of this one.